# php and mysql. view topics date

Tags: php, mysql

I can final exams assignment of lecturers to create a website forum.
and now there is a problem in my coding.
please fix.

when creating a topic / thread, and we opened the topic / threadnya, there is a date that tell us when the topic / thread made.
but in my coding, showing all existing date in the database.

```
    <?php
session_start();
if($_SESSION['logged'] == true)
{
    if(isset($_SESSION['username']))
    {   echo $username=$_SESSION["username"];
    }else
    {
    header('Location:login.php');
    }
}
?>



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<!==CSS>
<style>
#clock{
pointer-events: none
}
</style>
<!close css>

<img src="head1.jpg" alt="icon" width="100%" height="110">
<img src="line1.jpg" alt="icon" width="100%" height="20">
<title>Venray</title>
<body background="alienbackground.jpg">
<font face="comic sans MS">
<!==Table Login==>
<table border="0" style="width:99%" bgcolor="#424242" align="center">
<tr>
    <table border="0" style="width:98%" bgcolor="#424242" align="center">
    <tr>
        <td> <img src="start.gif" alt="icon" width="26" height="26">   </td>
            <td rowspan="2" align="right">
                <table border="0" bgcolor="#2E2E2E">

                <tr>
                    <td><b> 
<?php 
{
    echo "<tr><td><b><font color=green> Welcome, ";
    echo $username;
    echo '<a href="logout.php" style="text-decoration:none; color:red;"><span>, [Log Out]</span></a></li>';
    echo "</tr></td></b></font>";
    }
?>

                    </b></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td id=clock align="right"><b><iframe src="http://free.timeanddate.com/clock/i4eh41xm/n108/tlsg/fn7/fs12/tct/pct/ftb/tt0/tw1/tm1/th1" frameborder="0" width="182" height="20" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
</b></td>
                </tr>
                </table>
            </td>   
    </tr>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top"><b><font size="4">Community</font></b></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</tr>


<p style="color:#ff0000">

<!==Table please welcome==>
<table border="0" style="width:98%" bgcolor="#424242" align="center">

    <tr>
        <td align="right">
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);
require("conn.php");
$con = mysql_connect($server,$user,$pass);
$db = mysql_select_db($db);
$sql = "select * from d_admin order by username";
//echo $sql;
$ambil_data = mysql_query($sql);
while($data = mysql_fetch_array($ambil_data))
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM d_admin");
$rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
echo "Member " . $rows . " * ";
?>
        Post 1 * Topics 1 </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br>
<table border="1" width="98%" height="6%" align="center" bgcolor=#424242 >
    <tr>
        <td align="left" ><a href="forumuser.php"><img src="hometopic.gif" width="40" height="40"></a> </td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
        <table border="1" width="98%" height="40" align="center" bgcolor="#86B404" bordercolor=green>
        <tr>

        <th width="70%" align="left"><img src="open.png" width="40" height="40">Posting Display</th>
        <td align="right"><a href="replay"><img src="replay.png" width="150" height="40"></a></td>
        </tr>
    </tr>

        <tr>

            <table border="1" width="98%" height="70" align="center" bgcolor=#424242>


***<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);
$con = mysql_connect($server,$user,$pass);
$db = mysql_select_db($db);
$sql = "select * from tabel_topik ";
$ambil_data = mysql_query($sql);
while($data = mysql_fetch_array($ambil_data))
{
    echo '<tr><th align="left" valign="top" colspan="2" >'.$data['date'].'</th></tr>';
    echo '</tr>';
} 
?>***   


            <tr><th align="center" width="15%">Venray</th><td align="left" width="85%">title</td></tr>
            <tr><th align="top" width="15%">join dates</th><td align="left" rowspan="2" valign="top">awd</td></tr>
            <tr><th align="center" valign="top" width="15%" height="400">9 Post</th></tr>
            <tr>
            <td align="left">*</td>
            <td align="right" width="85%"><a href=""><img src="replay.png" width="150" height="40"></a></td></tr>
            </table>
        </tr>
</table>
</body>
</font>
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: you are fetching all the data from database and running a while loop adding a <tr> for every date. You need to run the query specific to that forum.

Comment: but i dont exactly know how to make it specific,can u fix it for me please?

Answer (score 0):

Get forum specific datas by passing the ID or any similar field in the query for starters. Then if you are looking to format the way in which the date is displayed, you could use the php date function like this:

```
while($data = mysql_fetch_array($ambil_data))
{
    echo '<tr><th align="left" valign="top" colspan="2" >'.date('jS M, Y',strtotime($data['date'])).'</th></tr>'; //format the date as required
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

Comment: sorry bro, yea it's changed my dates format, but this is not i want, my problem is when i echo the dates, it get every dates of thread i have out.here is the link for the result in image =http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=208z38h&s=8#.VHauaGev-KE.:D